# How to convert IQueryable to EntityCollection

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable, entitycollection

I really cannot find the answer about how to convert `IQueryable` to `EntityCollection`?

```
var userGroups = this.ObjectContext.UserGroups;

 foreach (var userGroup in userGroups )
 {
     var ussers = this.ObjectContext.Users.Where(f => f.UserGroupID == item.ID && f.IsActive == true);

     userGroup.Users = users; // Here I' am getting an issue.
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure because you don't specify, but I'm guessing that your `userGroup.Users` property is a navigation property generated by the EDMX model, so the entity collection is already created for you, all you need to do is add your users to the collection.

```
var userGroups = this.ObjectContext.UserGroups;

 foreach (var userGroup in userGroups )
 {
     var ussers = this.ObjectContext.Users.Where(f => f.UserGroupID == item.ID && f.IsActive == true);

     foreach(var user in ussers)
        userGroup.Users.Add(user);
 }
```

Comment: So there is no LINQ/ Helper class/ Something  to do it without FOREACH ?

Comment: LINQ is specifically designed to not have side effects, it is for querying.  What you're doing here is causing side effects, so it shouldn't be in an expansion method, it *should* be in a foreach.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, keep in mind than an IQueryable can be returned from _lots_ of different sources, it may not always contain entities from the entity framework.  You could of course easily create your own extension method that does the work for you.

Comment: @ClarkKent If you prefer, you can use: `users.ForEach`